# Not Trigger Data-Binding until Angular Controller data is loaded

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angular-promise

I'm trying to follow John Papa's [Controller Activation Process](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y080) where the data that a controller needs is loaded at the constructor of the controller. However, my page is triggering a lot of errors due to Angular trying to bind to a `null` object until the data is loaded.

## Example

Controller initializes and performs an AJAX call to fetch information about a movie. Meanwhile, the HTML tries to load information about the movie's director.

**Controller.js**

```
class MovieController {
  constructor(movieHttp) {
    this.movieHttp = movieHttp;
    this.movie = null;
    activate();
  }
  activate() {
    this.movieHttp.getMovie(...).then(movieData => { this.movie = movieData; });
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```
...
<span ng-bind="vm.movie.actor.name"></span>
...
```

Is there a nice way of resolving this issue other than changing the `ng-bind` into a function call, and then doing an `if (!this.movie) { return; }`?

Comment: You could wrap the whole thing in a `<div ng-if="vm.movie"></div>` tag. It won't be rendered (nor will any of its children be rendered) until `vm.movie` has been populated.

Comment: @Lex I tried doing this, but this is more than just whether the component is actually displayed. I'm using `ng-cloak` currently to hide the HTML until it's finished rendering, but accessing attributes of a `null` object triggers JavaScript errors which was the main thing I was trying to resolve. But thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an empty movie object on your ctrl (or better yet a service), and update it when the ajax calls returns:

```
  class MovieController {
    constructor(movieHttp) {
      this.movieHttp = movieHttp;
      this.movieData = {
         movie: {
            actor: {
               name: ''

            },
            title: ''
         }
      };
      activate();
   }
  activate() {
    this.movieHttp.getMovie(...).then(movieData => { this.movieData.movie = movieData;})
  }
 }
```

and your html:

```
    <span ng-bind="vm.movieData.movie.actor.name"></span>
```

it could be annoying if the object is very complex however you set it only once and than you can easily figure out what's the retured object structure is (again a better place to store it would be a service).

another solution is using the router resolve property which forces the promise to be reolved before the controller is instantiated (and injecting the resolved object as a parameter to your controller)
ui-router has a convinent way for that (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki), but angular's default router also has this option (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yeah, I was actually previously using `resolve` to load the data. However, following the John Papa conventions dictate that data used in the controller should be loaded in the data, which was why I was refactoring to follow that situation. I ended did just creating a stub object to initialize the controller with until the ajax returns.